# what is the bitcoin.conf for testnet3?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet

I need to use bitcoin testnet3 server for testing via php.

> **bitcoin.conf**
>
> rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
>
> rpcpassword=random string
>
> testnet=1
>
> **create JsonRpc object with easy bitcoin**:
>
> $bitcoin = new Bitcoin('bitcoinrpc', 'random string', 'localhost', 18332);

what is the solution for this? does rpc port is right for tesnet3 server?

Comment: Yeah, that all looks fine. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: @NickODell I thought Bitcoind/cli was disabled without the the `daemon`/`server` flags?

Comment: note: `mainnet` and `testnet rpcpassword` are same